# Should I jump into sparkling pits?

Tags: moonlighter

In Moonlighter I've noticed some of the pits sparkle, but I don't seem to be able to interact with them besides jumping in. Is this right? Or is there a smarter way of checking the bottom of these pits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based from this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Moonlighter/comments/8n41ff/shining_pit_secret_areas/)

> If you see sparkles in a pit when you walk in a room you can jump down and enter a secret area that will give you a chest that teleports items back to your room or an idol that spawns progressively harder waves of enemies for progressively better treasure chests.

Comment: Is there a specific place when you can see the sparkle. I never know so I just randomly roll into pits.